# Como mostrar una tabla MySQL en HTML?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un problema al enlazar una DB y mostrarla en una página HTML en una tabla.

He realizado la conexión a la base de datos de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php 
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("a6113712_IESPADB", $connect) or die(mysql_error()); 
?>
```

El código del botón es el siguiente

```
<?php
include"connexion.php";

if(is set($_POST['search'])) {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM alumnos ";
    $search_termn =  mysql_real_escape_string("POST"['Nombre']);
    $search_termp =  mysql_real_escape_string("POST"['ApeidoP']);
    $search_termm =  mysql_real_escape_string("POST"['ApeidoM']);
    $search_termc =  mysql_real_escape_string("POST"['Cuip']);
    $sql .=" WHERE (NOMBRE = '{$search_termn}') AND (ApeidoPaterno = {$search_termp}') AND (ApeidoMaterno = {$search_termm}' ) ";
}

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

?>
<!--<<form name="search_form" method="POST" action="display.php">
Search: <input type="text" name="search_box" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="search" value="search the table..">
</form>-->

<table width="70%" cellpadding="5" cellspace="5">

<tr>
    <td><strong>NombreDeClase</strong></td>
    <td><strong>IDT</strong></td>
    <td><strong>CUIP</strong></td>
    <td><strong>NOMBRE</strong></td>
    <td><strong>ApeidoPaterno</strong></td>
    <td><strong>ApeidoMaterno</strong></td>
    <td><strong>DirigidoA</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Docente</strong></td>
    <td><strong>AñoDeInicio</strong></td>
    <td><strong>MesDeInicio</strong></td>
    <td><strong>DiaDeInicio</strong></td>
    <td><strong>AñoDeTerminacion</strong></td>
    <td><strong>MesDeTerminacion</strong></td>
    <td><strong>DiaDeTerminacion</strong></td>
    <td><strong>HorasCursadas</strong></td>
    <td><strong>CA</strong></td>
    <td><strong>NO</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Cargo</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Procedencia</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Dependencia</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Libro</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Foja</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Califiaciones</strong></td>
</tr>
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {?>
    <td><?php echo $row['NombreDeClase'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['IDT'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['CUIP'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['NOMBRE'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['ApeidoPaterno'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['ApeidoMaterno'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['DirigidoA'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Docente'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['AñoDeInicio'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['MesDeInicio'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['DiaDeInicio'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['AñoDeTerminacion'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['MesDeTerminacion'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['DiaDeTerminacion'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['HorasCursadas'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['CA'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['NO'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Cargo'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Procedencia'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Dependencia'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Libro'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Foja'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Califiaciones'] ?></td>
<?php} ?>

</table>
```

Comment: que error aparece?

Comment: Consejo:  mysql-real-escape-string te protege contra ataques SQL-injections ... pero no del todo, y no es aconsejable. Pasate a prepared statements http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string

Answer (score 1):

Hay un error en la consulta SQL, te faltan un par de comillas que harán que todo falle:

```
$sql .=" WHERE (NOMBRE = '{$search_termn}') AND (ApeidoPaterno = {$search_termp}') AND (ApeidoMaterno = {$search_termm}' ) ";
```

Debería ser de este otro modo:

```
$sql .=" WHERE (NOMBRE = '{$search_termn}') AND (ApeidoPaterno = '{$search_termp}') AND (ApeidoMaterno = '{$search_termm}' ) ";
```

Nota que he añadido las comillas de apertura para `{$search_termp}` y `{$search_termm}`. Idealmente sería mejor usar consultas preparadas que evitarán posibles problemas si los valores contienen comillas (y te ahorrarán quebraderos de cabeza con vulnerabilidades de inyección SQL).

Aparte de eso, tienes que añadir filas en la tabla, ahora mismo sólo estás añadiendo celdas en el bucle, lo que hará que todas se muestren en una misma fila. Prueba a cambiar el código a esto:

```
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['NombreDeClase'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['IDT'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['CUIP'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['NOMBRE'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['ApeidoPaterno'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['ApeidoMaterno'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['DirigidoA'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Docente'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['AñoDeInicio'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['MesDeInicio'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['DiaDeInicio'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['AñoDeTerminacion'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['MesDeTerminacion'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['DiaDeTerminacion'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['HorasCursadas'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['CA'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['NO'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Cargo'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Procedencia'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Dependencia'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Libro'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Foja'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Califiaciones'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php} ?>
```