# ¿Como muestro los registros en una tabla?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Documento sin título

Hola, soy muy novato en php y mi profesor nos ha encargado hacer un CRUD
he conseguido mostrar los registros de la base de datos. pero, me ha pedido que se muestren en una tabla y no tengo idea de como hacerlo, trate de hacerlo metiendo html pero dado mi bajo conocimiento no pude. espero puedan ayudarme quiero aprender.

```
$registros = mysqli_query( $conexion, "select *
                    from datosfrutas where id='$_POST[datoBuscar]'" )or
die( "Problemas en el select:" . mysqli_error( $conexion ) );


if ( $reg = mysqli_fetch_array( $registros ) )


{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "El nombre es:" . $reg[ 'Nombre' ] . "<br>";
    echo "El Id es:" . $reg[ 'Id' ] . "<br>";
    echo "¿Es endemica?:" . $reg[ 'Endemica' ] . "<br>";
    echo "Pais de origen:" . $reg[ 'Pais' ] . "<br>";
    echo "Es de color:" . $reg[ 'Color' ] . "<br>";
    echo "Tiene sabor:" . $reg[ 'Sabor' ] . "<br>";
    echo "Su consistencia es:" . $reg[ 'Consistencia' ] . "<br>";
    echo "Su incidencia es:" . $reg[ 'Incidencia' ] . "<br>";

} else {
    echo "No existe una fruta con ese Id.";
}
mysqli_close( $conexion );
?>
```

Comment: Posible [Duplicado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16156/como-mostrar-una-tabla-mysql-en-HTML)

Comment: Hola buenas tarde, el proceso es sencillo. Solo tienes que insertar la estructura de la tabla html intercalándola dentro de php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta esto:

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><td>El nombre es:</td><td>" . $reg[ 'Nombre' ] . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>El Id es:</td><td>" . $reg[ 'Id' ] . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>¿Es endemica?:</td><td>" . $reg[ 'Endemica' ] . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Pais de origen:</td><td>" . $reg[ 'Pais' ] . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Es de color:</td><td>" . $reg[ 'Color' ] . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Tiene sabor:</td><td>" . $reg[ 'Sabor' ] . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Su consistencia es:</td><td>" . $reg[ 'Consistencia' ] . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Su incidencia es:</td><td>" . $reg[ 'Incidencia' ] . "</td></tr></table>";
```

Comment: Gracias. si me funciono.

Comment: De nada, y como menciona Shadow Paz.  Puedes crear una variable con todo tu HTML y llamar echo una sola vez.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un bucle como while por ejemplo y después mediante mysqli_fetch_assoc para convertir el resultado de tu consulta a un array asociativo, es decir formato clave valor.

Por otro lado dejar la estructura genérica de la tabla fuera del while y solo meter las etiquetas tr y td dentro del while para crear las columnas y filas necesarias

```
<?php
$html = '<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="es-Mx">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Reporte de Activos</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h3>Reporte de Animales Disecados Activos<h3>
            <table>
            <tr> 
                <td>Nombre</td>
                <td>Familia</td>
                <td>Origen</td>
            </tr>';
            include('../librerias/conecta.php');
            $MuestraTodosInsectos = "SELECT * FROM tbanimalesdisecados WHERE status <> 0";
            $EjecutaMuestraTodosInsectos = mysqli_query($MuestraTodosInsectos);
                while($Filas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($EjecutaMuestraTodosInsectos))
                {
                    $html .= '
                  <tr>
                  <td> '.$Filas["nombre_animal"].'</td>
                  <td> '.$Filas["familia_animal"].'</td>
                  <td> '.$Filas["origen_animal"].'</td>
                  </tr>';
                }
                $html .= '</table>
        </body>
        </html>';

        echo $html;
```

Al final como puedes notar le hago un echo a la variable que tiene contenido todo el código.

> Te muestro un ejemplo con un while por que es útil para recorrer n
>   cantidad de registros que tenga tu tabla, del mismo modo use toda una estructura HTML en el código pero no es estrictamente necesario; pudieras sustituir todo eso o quitarlo y solo dejar el méro código de la tabla o que genera la tabla

Comment: Gracias, lo he conseguido pero tomare en cuenta lo que me indicas.

Comment: lo hiciste de esta manera o de otra? @DigitalRenegade

Comment: Use el codigo de una respuesta anterior.

Comment: perfecto que bueno te quedó

Comment: sin embargo considera la cantidad de echos usados

Comment: para que sirve el $html ?

Comment: @DigitalRenegade simplemente es el nombre de una variable cualquiera, le pude poner digital y serviría igual

Comment: el echo $html al final del codigo imprimiria la tabla sin necesidad de tanto echo, no?

Comment: si es la idea pero igual necesitas adaptarlo a tus necesidades

Comment: perfecto, ya le empiezo a entender a tu propuesta de código, gracias,hasta luego.

Comment: la respuesta que elijas al final márcala por favor como aceptada, cualquiera que sea que te sirva